# deploying web app in tomcat7

Tags: mysql, deployment, tomcat7

i've already deployed a web app in tomcat7 and all i have to do is to start the app, but every time i try to start the web app i always got this error:

> FAIL - Application at context path /agileexpress could not be started

and this is what i got on my log, seem like i am having a problem with my sql

```
May 15, 2015 4:54:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 35067 ms
May 15, 2015 4:55:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 15, 2015 4:55:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/agileexpress] startup failed due to previous errors
May 15, 2015 4:55:39 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/agileexpress] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 15, 2015 4:55:39 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/agileexpress] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

can anyone help me? i'm a newbie on tomcat7

Comment: There must be an error in one of the other logfiles.

Comment: Did you check catalina.out ?

Comment: @Orchun : same error.

Answer (score 0):

Move your JDBC drivers to the Tomcat (common classloader) lib/ directory (defined in the `catalina.properties` file, which is usually located in `CATALINA_HOME/lib`).  This will tell the common classloader to load the driver and there should be no problem with your webapp classloader.

Comment: what if i am using apache2 too? wouldn't it affect apache2?

Comment: Not sure if it would affect your Apache server.  Could you try moving the driver to see if it allows Tomcat to start without error?  If so, then we can work on the Apache problem.